# To combine two GridViews which have different data into one GridView

Tags: c#, gridview

How to combine two different GridViews into single GridView. I have used SQL query for one and Linq query for one. Can anyone help in this?

Thanks

Comment: Your question is too broad, there can be only one answer, or the answer would be too long to write. Please precise your question and bring some code sample of your `GridViews` and content, and how you initialize them, etc.

Answer (score 0):

You don't combine the gridviews, you combine the sources.